# loading "mat" file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to load a mat file in Matlab by:

```
file = 'DSC (1)';
load file;
```

but I get this error:

`Unable to read file 'file'. No such file or directory.`

On the other hand by:

```
load 'DSC (1)';
```

It works.

Any idea, why the first one does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the Matlab script syntax, rather than the (recommended) function syntax.

`load(file)`  would execute load on the contents of variable `file`. As the variable file contains a string with the right location, this will work.

However `load file` or `load 'file'` will execute load on the string `'file'`. As there is no file called 'file' this will not work.